# Getting array values into a string

Tags: php

I output a PHP object via a loop but withing this look I have a few nested arrays.

```
[categories] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Chinese
        [1] => chinese
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Vietnamese
        [1] => vietnamese
    )
)

[phone] => 5123355555
```

I can get the phone like this:

```
$response->businesses[$x]->phone
```

How do I get categories (first value) into a string like this:

```
Chinese, Vietnamese
```

Comment: just implode the array.

Comment: @FrayneKonok NO. Read the question.

Comment: @santa, did you need this through an function or a loop in raw code of php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
implode(', ', array_map(function($item) {
       return $item[0];
}, $response->businesses[$x]->categories));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) :

```
$newArray = array_column($response->businesses[$x]->categories, 0);
```

It returns an array with the column `0`. So the response will be:

```
print_r($newArray);
//Array ( [0] => Chinese [1] => Vietnamese )
```

Then you can join it safely:

```
$newString = implode(",", $newArray)
echo $newString; // "Chinese, Vietnamese"
```

Comment: Yes, this is it, i was looking for it it in the Manual.

Comment: What are you looking for? The `array_column()` function? I share the direct link to php.net

Comment: Because i am not an expert, so i was looking for a function that can do the job, so i got late to answer, But one person give me a negative vote. Its not my wrong that i did a answer that is same to your answer.

Comment: I'm not downvoted you, but I think that your efforts was fine. Sorry.